# LAMP in the cloud

Tags: lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

For my job, I have to use lots of LAMP-based systems like Wordpress.  Is there a cloud service out there that can simply give me virtual LAMP servers on-demand so that I can, for example:

Download the complete filesystem of a Wordpress site, "spin up" a LAMP instance solely for developing that Wordpress site, upload the filesystem, develop the site, and then when I'm done developing, I just take a new snapshot of that filesystem for delivery to my client and kill the LAMP instance.

Basically I'm just asking for a pool of sandboxes in which to develop Wordpress sites without having to set up any LAMP stuff.

Comment: The vast majority of VPS and cloud hosting providers out there use primarily a LAMP stack by default.

Answer (score 0):

This website seems to be what your looking for

http://www.tmdhosting.com/wordpress-3-dedicated-hosting.html